# Rails fields_for form not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**products_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.build_discount
end
```

**product.rb**

```
has_many :discounts, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :discounts
attr_accessible :discounts_attributes
```

**discount.rb**

```
belongs_to :product
```

**_edit_product.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(product, :html => { :multipart => true  }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    // STUFF
    <%= f.fields_for :discounts do |discount_form| %>
       //does not show up
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The content in the `fields_for` block does not show up. However, if I change `has_many :discounts` to `has_many :discount`, the form shows up (get mass assignment error when I try to submit).

Any ideas as to why the form is not rendering in the `fields_for` block and why it does render when I change the pluralization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want **many** discounts or **one** discount?

`@product.build_discount` is used in a `has_one` association, but the rest of your code is for `has_many`

If you want **many** discounts then change it to `@product.discounts.build`

Otherwise, if you want just **one** discount, change the following:

`f.fields_for :discount do |discount_form|` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :discount` to singular.

`@products.discounts.build` won't work because you can't get an association from a collection of objects. For example:

```
@products = Product.all
@discount = @products.discounts.build
# This won't work! You'll get an error

@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@discount = @product.discounts.build
# This will work, since you're running it on a single instance of Product
```

Comment: Made that change. The edit partial is being rendered on index. In the index action, I get all the products of the current user '@product = current_user.products'. Adding '@products.discounts.build' throws an undefined method "discounts" error.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the local variable `product` to your `_edit_product.html.erb` partial? I'm guessing you have a `new.html.erb` view where you render your partial?

Comment: My comment above answers this question. Thanks.

Comment: You're assigning a collection of products to `@product` here `@product = current_user.products`, then referencing `@products` (which as far as I can tell, doesn't exist) here `@products.discounts.build`.

Answer (score 0):

Using @mind_blank's answer, I wrote this solution:

`@products = current_user.products.each {|product| product.discounts.build}`

The form showed up after this line.